# Java auto-triggering works wrongly with YCM + Eclim

Tags: java, eclipse, vim, eclim

I use YCM + Eclim for Java completion. After eclim installed, I add `let g:EclimCompletionMethod = 'omnifunc'` in my .vimrc and start eclim server. When I type `:PingEclilm` in Vim, it returns `eclim 2.4.0` and `eclipse 4.4.0`.

Then I use `:ProjectCreate /path/to/project -n java` creating an Eclipse project. But when I edit a java source file, I find the auto-triggering function works not well. It always trigger something wrong.

For example:

[image]

There is a [setDefaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-) method in JFrame, but it never appear in the popup window.

Do someone have a perfect solution?

Comment: I can't replicate this. Mine gives me the expected result. (Also your completions don't make any sense for what you have typed). Do you have any compilation errors in your file (I don't know if this matters for java). Try restarting eclim. Make sure your class path is correct in the .classpath file.

Comment: I have no compilation errors and I can build the Eclipse project successfully. And it makes no sense when I restart eclim.

Comment: I have no idea you might consider asking on the eclim mailing list. (And if you get an answer post back here with the solution/problem)